# Behaviour of fetchrow_hashref in Perl

Tags: perl, dbi

I am trying to execute a procedure from Perl and store the results in a text file (on Windows). I am using DBI's 
    fetchrow_hashref() to fetch row results. The stored procedure that I am trying to execute returns more than 5 million rows. I want to know the functionality "behind-the-scene" - particularly what happens during the 
    fetchrow_hashref() call. e.g. Perl executes the procedure, the procedure returns all the impacted rows, keeps it in a pool (either on Database side or the calling machine side?) and then Perl selects the rows from resultset one by one. Does it happen that way or something else?

Comment: The database is MSSQL Server

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question to answer as you've not said which Perl database driver you are using. I'm assuming you are using DBD::ODBC and the MS SQL Server ODBC Driver in this answer.

When you call prepare on the SQL calling the procedure the ODBC driver sends it to MS SQL Server where the procedure is parsed. On calling execute the procedure is started (how you progress through the procedure depends on a lot of things). Assuming the first thing in your procedure is a select a cursor will be created for the query and MS SQL Server will start sending the rows back to the ODBC Driver (it uses the TDS protocol). In the mean time DBD::ODBC will make ODBC calls to the driver which tells it there is a result-set (SQLNumResultCol returns a non zero value). DBD::ODBC will then query the driver for the types of the columns in the result-set and bind them (SQLBindCol).

Each time you call fetchrow_hashref, DBD::ODBC will call SQLFetch, the ODBC driver will read a row from the socket and copy the data to the bound buffers.

There are important things to realise here. Mostly MS SQL Server will write a lot of rows initially to the socket even though the ODBC driver is probably not reading them yet. As a result, if you close your statement the driver has to read a lot of rows from the socket and throw them away. If you use a non standard cursor or enable Multiple Active Statements in the driver then rows are sent back to the driver one at a time so the ODBC driver can ask the server to move forward, backward in the result-set or request a row from result-set 1 then result-set 2.

There are other areas a little unusual when using procedures like whether nocount is enabled or not and you progress through your procedure statements using SQLMoreResults (odbc_more_results). Also, the output parameters in a procedure are no available until SQLMoreResults returns false.

You may find [Multiple Active Statements (MAS) and DBD::ODBC](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/perl/multiple-active-statements.html) of some interest to you or [may some of the other articles](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/perl/index.html). You may also want to read about the TDS protocol.